# accessing nested array key,value from json in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am new in javascript. It may be a basic thing but I am stuck with it.
here is my json:

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "status": "success",
    "data": [
        [
            {
                "city": "Alexandria",
                "country": "Egypt",

            },
            {
                "city": "Alexandria",
                "country": "Egypt",

            },]]
```

I want to access this:

```
0: {city: "Alexandria", country: "Egypt"}
1: {city: "Antalya", country: "Turkey"}
```

I tried this code :

```
getData = function (data) {
    keys = Object.keys(data[0]);
    data = [];
    keys.forEach(function (key) {
        data.push(key);
    });
    return data;
}
```

which returns this:

```
0: "0"
1: "1"
2: "2"
3: "3"
4: "4"
5: "5"
6: "6
```

please help me!

Comment: Expected output?

Comment: `obj.data[0]` will give you your array

Comment: What do you used to get the data like this http, jquery ajax please be more clear so we can help you

Comment: can you help me by modifying the method I am trying ..

Comment: @YosvelQuintero 0: {city: "Alexandria", country: "Egypt"}
1: {city: "Antalya", country: "Turkey"}

Comment: `function (data) { return data[0] }`?

Comment: I think you did not provide enough data. Where is `Turkey` in JSON? in `obj.data[1]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get first element of response's `data` array as `result`:

```js
const response = {
  "statusCode": 200,
  "status": "success",
  "data": [
    [{
        "city": "Alexandria",
        "country": "Egypt",

      },
      {
        "city": "Alexandria",
        "country": "Egypt",

      },
    ]
  ]
}
const getData = ({ data: [result] = [[]] }) => result

console.log(getData(response))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
getData = function(data){
    arr = data.data[0];
    new_data = []
    for(var item in arr){
        new_data.push(arr[item])
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

First, your `data[0]` is an array, then `Object.keys(array)` will return an array of `index` of that `array`. Ex:

```
array= [{x: 1}, {x: 2}, {x: 3}]
Object.keys(array) // ['0', '1', '2']
```

So what you pushed to the return array are just the index like what you showed.

Second, you should use the different variable name to avoid misunderstanding. In this case, is `data` variable.

I updated the function

```js
const object = {"statusCode": 200,"status": "success","data": [[{"city": "Alexandria","country": "Egypt",},{"city": "Alexandria","country": "Egypt",},]]}

getData = function (arr) {
  data = []
  arr[0].forEach(function (key) {
    data.push(key);
  });
  return data
}

console.log(getData(object.data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to extract the `data` from the object and the array:

```js
const getData = ({ data: [data] = [] } = {}) => data;

const response = {"statusCode":200,"status":"success","data":[[{"city":"Alexandria","country":"Egypt"},{"city":"Alexandria","country":"Egypt"}]]};

console.log(getData(response));
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Comment: Your `responseData` is `undefined` or `null` or your trying to handle the `responseData` outside of the async all. I've added default values to prevent errors, but you should why the responseData is `undefined`, or the `data` inside it is.